# Distribution of the ratio of exponential r.vs with additive constant

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

I'm interested in the distribution of $\frac{X}{c+X+Y}$, where $X$ and $Y$ follows the exponential distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$, and $c$ is a constant.

I know that without the constant $c$, this ratio has a uniform$(0,1)$ distribution. However, this is not the case when adding the constant $c$.

Trying to follow the same methodology in [here](https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/the-distribution-of-xxy-is-uniform-when-x-and-y-are-iid-exponential/). I have the following.

For $\alpha \in [0,1)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Pr \left(\frac{X}{c+X+Y} \leq \alpha\right) &=& \Pr \left(\frac{c+X+Y}{X} \geq \frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\\
&=& \Pr\left(Y \geq X(1/\alpha -1) -c\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Noting that $X(1/\alpha -1) -c \geq 0$ only for $X \geq \frac{c \alpha}{1-\alpha}$, For simplicity, let's assume that $\lambda =c=1$, thus, we obtain
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Pr \left(\frac{X}{1+X+Y} \leq \alpha\right)  &=& \int_{0}^{\alpha/(1-\alpha)}  e^{- x}\cdot 1 \mathrm{d}x + \int_{\alpha/(1-\alpha)}^\infty \lambda e^{-x} e^{- x(\frac{1}{\alpha}-1) -1} \mathrm{d}x
&=& 1-e^{-\alpha/(1-\alpha)} +  \alpha e^{-\frac{1}{1-\alpha} -1}
\end{eqnarray*}

However, simulations I made shows that this is not true.

What have I missed? Is there more general result for ratio of the form $\frac{X}{c + \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}$?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: The PDF of $$T_n=\frac{X}{c+X+Y_1+\cdots+Y_n}$$ where $c>0$ and $X$ and $(Y_k)$ are i.i.d. exponential of parameter $\lambda$ is $$f_n(t)=\left(n+\frac{\lambda c}{1-t}\right)(1-t)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda ct/(1-t)}\mathbf 1_{0<t<1}.$$

Comment: Thanks @Did for this generalization! Can you please tell me how did you obtained this result ? Does it has a meaning in order statistical sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compute the LHS, you should first condition on the event that $Y$ takes the value $y$, and then integrate this with respect to the marginal density of $y$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\text{Pr}\left(\frac{X}{X+Y+c}\leq \alpha\right)&=\text{Pr}\left(X\leq \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}(Y+c)\right)\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\text{Pr}\left(X\leq \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}(y+c)\right)f_{Y}(y)~dy\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\text{Pr}\left(X\leq \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}(y+c)\right)\lambda e^{-\lambda y}~dy.
\end{align}

Under the assumption that $\lambda=c=1$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$, the above simplifies to
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Pr}\left(\frac{X}{X+Y+1}\leq \alpha\right)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\alpha (y+1)}{1-\alpha}}e^{-x} e^{-y}~dx~dy.
\end{eqnarray}
You may now proceed to do the calculations as usual.

Comment: Thanks @Karthik ! Your answer is correct. Still, can you please point out what is the problem with $\int_0^{\alpha/(1-\alpha)}e^{-x} \mathrm{d}x$ ? Since in this region we known that $\Pr (Y > x(1/\alpha -1)) =1$, I would expect that it will be  equivalent to what you did.

Comment: @sefi You are welcome. I do not find any logical error in what you have done, but I feel that in the second integral you have on the RHS, it should be $\int\limits_{\alpha/(1-\alpha)}^{\infty} e^{-x} e^{-x(1/\alpha -1)+1}~dx$ and not $\int\limits_{\alpha/(1-\alpha)}^{\infty} e^{-x} e^{-x(1/\alpha -1)-1}~dx$. Can you please check if I am right?